# Invalid Parameter exception

Tags: c#, json.net

I am working on a navigation windows phone 8.1 application. I as using a try catch block for error handling. As soon as I send and invalid input to the server something like "dfkdsf", it throws me a runtime exception error stating Invalid Parameter but the catch block doesn't handle it. where am I going wrong?

```
public async void GetSearchAPIData()
    {
        try
        {
            JArray arr = JArray.Parse(await responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            foreach (JObject obj in arr.Children<JObject>())    //exception thrown here!
            {
                noOfResult++;
                JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
                settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
                var rcvdData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocationData>(obj.ToString(), settings);
                //adding recieved data into a list..
                RcvdSearchDataList.Add(rcvdData);
            }
            //changing current status on status bar..
            statusBar.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Found " + noOfResult + " results for " + "\"" + UserRequestedLocation + "\"";
            statusBar.ProgressIndicator.ProgressValue = 0;

            if (RcvdSearchDataList.Count == 0)
            {
                statusBar.ProgressIndicator.Text = "We're Sorry! No matches found...";
                statusBar.ProgressIndicator.ProgressValue = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                ResultListView = new ListView() { Margin = new Thickness(20), VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch };
                ResultDataGrid.Children.Add(ResultListView);
                for (int i = 0; i < RcvdSearchDataList.Count; i++)
                {
                    UpdateSearchTextData(i);
                }
            }
            UpdateSearchMapData(RcvdSearchDataList);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Format(
                    "An error occurred while looking for the requested location.\r\n\r\n{0:x}\r\n\r\n{1}", "HRESULT: " + e.HResult, "Message: " + e.Message);
            ErrorDialog.Content = errorMessage;
            await ErrorDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

the JArray arr has a returned value of {[]} from the server which I am not able to handle

Comment: does this line responce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() spawns a new thread? and exception is trown in that thread?....can you post stack trace?

Comment: show your model.or check with your db column , may be parameters name are mismatch.as i believe

Comment: @PankajGupta The model is perfect. everything works fine if it's an ideal case like someone searched for Delhi or also if he misspelled delhi as delphi or something but I am just making my application handle the exceptions if user tries to play around.

Comment: @Viru The exception is thrown in the foreach loop as the JArray arr gets the returned value from the server as {[]} ... I am not able to handle this value. PS: I am new to Json.

Comment: can you comment this line  settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
 and try again

Comment: @Viru yes that was it. It solved it. If I may ask what was happening there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment the line `settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore`.
 you are telling Json Serializer to ignore null values during deserilization.
So when you got empty Json repsonse, it did not deserialize it and somehow caused that invalid paramter exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I was asking about that somehow thing itself.. how did it caused it to through an invalid parameter exception. Also if I tell the Json serializer not to ignore nulls so won't it cause an issue if the response is a 200 OK from the API but some values inside the Response are null while storing them in a  class